# Getting undefined database errors in console after using Meteor reset to reset my DB

Tags: meteor

Here are the condensed cliffs:

- I decided to do a meteor reset and wipe all users and entries in my DB to test my app from scratch before deployment
- Suddenly, I'm getting errors printed in the console like the following: 
  [image]
- My app works fine, everything inserts and updated in the DB like it should, but these pesky errors keep popping up in the console. The database is properly imported into my React component as well.

Any ideas what could cause these errors?

Code for "inserResults":

```
insertResults: function(data, userIP){
  if(Results.findOne({"data.id": data.questionId})){
    Results.update({"data.id": data.questionId}, {$push: {"data.choices": data.choices[0], "data.ip": userIP, "data.timeTracker": data.timeTracker[0]}, $set: {"data.lastResponse": data.lastResponse}});
  } else{
  Results.insert({data}, function(error, result){
    if(!error){
      Results.update({"data.id": data.questionId}, {$push: {"data.ip": userIP}});
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for 'insertResults' - something is going wrong in there. I would guess that a db query into 'Results' has no data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing an undefined object called 'Results' to the method 'insertResults' which I'm assuming puts them into the database? Have you tried checking the invocations of this method and could you maybe post the method in question?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing that's undefined. This happens to every method that's called from the client. Doesn't matter which method it is, but the database is always logged in the console as undefined, when in reality, it's not and the entire process works.